# Create with imshow the same plot as pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have an array ( 256 X 128 ) which i am plotting using python and matplotlib with `imshow` and `pcolormesh`. When i am using `pcolormesh` I am getting the plot as it should be while when i am using `imshow` i am getting something different which is expected as i understand but it is wrong. Since i want the quality output of `imshow`, is it possible to get with `imshow` the same output as `pcolormesh` for given array ? Can i, for example, transform the array to get with `imshow` the same output created by `pcolormesh`?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What is *wrong* when using `imshow`? What do you mean by *the quality output of `imshow`? Do you mean the interpolation that `imshow` applies?

Comment: Yes by quality i mean the interpolation that is provided by imshow. I have tried pcolormesh with interpolation but for reasons unknown to me the output cannot be saved in eps format needed for latex. Also when i am  using imshow i am getting the plot upside down compared with the plot produced by pcolormesh.

Comment: @MavridisM. for the upsidedown problem you can try origin='lower' in your imshow parameters.

Comment: Setting origin = 'lower' worked and gives me the same output image. Thank you for your help and i am sorry if the answer seems obvious for you.  I have just started using matplotlib.

Comment: it is related since it has to do with the way imshow uses the input array although it is not the same question, which i was unaware of.